# SQL Statement how to retrieve a data which have 2 or more record?

Tags: sql

I have a Car table and User table which store car and user particular. and a RentRecord table to store which user have rent certain car and date. I want to retrieve the user who have rent car more than 2 times, how to write the sql statement, i try using count and group by but in the end i only get one row data.

```
Select count(rr.userId) as T, userName, carType 
from rentrecord rr 
inner join user u on u.userId = rr.userId 
inner join car c on c.carId = rr.carId 
group by (rr.userId) having T>=2;
```

how can i modify the sql statement so it return user record who have rent car more than 2 times. Sorry let me cclarify it, it return only one records, i need to list out the records details. I mean for example User A rent CarA and CarB so inside rentrecord table should have 2 row data, i need retrieve this 2 row data.  Sorry for ambigous.

Comment: Rented any car two or more times or rented the exact same car two or more times?

Comment: any car i just want to retrieve user who borrow car two times or more before

Comment: please clarify what you're looking for. The query already seems to return data from the user record (`userName`).

It would help if you included the tables you're querying from.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question already

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rented any car two or more times:

```
select userID,COUNT(*)
from rentRecord
group by userID
having COUNT(*) > 2
```

Rented one particular car two or more times:

```
select userID,carID,COUNT(*)
from rentRecord
group by userID,carID
having COUNT(*) > 2
```

Rented one particular car (with an obvious single car type) two or more times, with additional data:

```
select userID,username,cartype,Cnt
from (select userID,carID,COUNT(*) as Cnt
    from rentRecord
    group by userID,carID
    having COUNT(*) > 2) multi
      inner join
    user u
       on
         multi.userID = u.UserID
      inner join
    car c
       on
         multi.carID = c.CarID
```

---

Based on edit - return all rental info for a user who has rented multiple cars:

```
SELECT
     * /* TODO - Specify columns */
from
     [User] u
        inner join
     rentRecord rr
         on
              u.UserID = rr.UserID
        inner join
     Car c
        on
              rr.CarID = c.CarID
where
    u.UserID in (select UserID from (select userID,COUNT(*) Cnt
                    from rentRecord
                    group by userID
                    having COUNT(*) >= 2) t)
```

I've used the following tables, since we don't currently have a schema from the OP:

```
create table [User] (
    UserID int not null
)
go
insert into [User](UserID)
select 1 union all
select 2
go
create table Car (
    CarID int not null
)
go
insert into Car(CarID)
select 1 union all
select 2
go
create table rentRecord (
    UserID int not null,
    CarID int not null
)
go
insert into rentRecord(UserID,CarID)
select 1,1 union all
select 1,2 union all
select 2,1 union all
select 2,2
go
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry i just edited my question i need to return the record, not just which user but the rental record.

Comment: @user236501 - I've updated my answer - I think my bottom query does what you want

Comment: I mean if there have more than one user rent 2 times above car it won't work

Comment: @user236501 - really? I've used this construct plenty of times in the past and it's worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for your solution appreciated it.

Answer (score 2):

in mysql syntax

```
SELECT 
A.id, COUNT(B.id) 
FROM userTable A 
LEFT JOIN rentRecordTable B on B.user_id_of_rent = A.id
GROUP BY A.id
HAVING COUNT(B.id) > 2
```

Comment: Why *left* join when you know you're looking for users with *at least* two rentals?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry i just edited my question i need to return the record, not just which user but the rental record.

Comment: Using the join makes a super record.  You have all the columns of each user and related rental record in the select, just add in teh columns you want